# Correctly RedirectToAction with Post

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, jquery

I have some action

```
        [HttpPost]
        public ActionResult FiltersSetup()
        {            
            return RedirectToAction("ActionTwo",routes);
        }
```

In client I use

```
   $.ajax({
       type: 'POST',
       url: '/FiltersSetup',
       data: postData,
       traditional: true
   });
```

If I send data through the html form of all site content updates, but when a jQuery.post () the content is not updated. In firebug Post request is completed, but GET request does not end there.

Comment: Your question is extremely unclear. You have shown some POST action that takes no arguments. Then you have shown some javascript AJAX call invoking this action and using the `data` property to send some parameters. Then you talk about some html form. Then you talk about some content. I don't get it. What's the problem here? Please try reformulating your question. I don't understand what you are talking about here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may want to check the URL. I suggest using url: '@Url.Action("foo")', which will build the correct URL.